# How retrieve or generate .svcmap file by command line or programmatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wcf, svcutil.exe

I need to retrieve or generate the WCF file .svcmap using the command line. I normally add or update the services references using Visual Studio (Update Service Reference / Add Services Reference), but I need to do this task programmatically now.

So far I found: `svcutil.exe` which is a good way to retrieve and generate some part of the needed files:

```
output.config  
*.cs  
*.wsdl
```

But is still missing the `.svcmap` which I have read is a very important file and the `.datasource` files. Can someone knows how to recreate programmatically what Visual Studio does in this case??

Answer (score 1):

Try Below command line:

```
svcutil /t:code http://<service_url> /out:<file_name>.cs /config:<file_name>.config
```

Comment: I already tried that, and I still have the same problem the .svcmap file is not generated or retrieved in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong about the `.svcmap` file, it is just a configuration file for Add Service Reference feature in VS. There is no need for the `.svcmap` file if what I need is generate the service client code programmatically. Everything needed is the `.cs` and the `.config` file and for that, I just need to use `svcutil.exe`